# Dropdown to control content of multiple Iframes on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

All,

New programmer here, so thanks for any help.

I'm working with a number of files and i'd like to link the selection from the drop down box to what is contained in 4 Iframes on the page.

I can code the options so that each Iframe has a drop down for selection, but I cant figure out how to control all four iframes with just one drop down at the top.

```
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function newSrc() {
    var e = document.getElementById("MySelectMenu");
    var newSrc = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("MyFrame").src=newSrc;
   }

  </script>
<style type="text/css">select {clear:both;}
</style>
<p dir="ltr"><iframe id="MyFrame" src="MainIntropage1.html" style="width: 
700px; height: 750px;"></iframe><select id="MySelectMenu"><option 
value="Option1page1.html">Option1</option><option 
value="Opion2page1.html">Option2</option><option 
value="Option3page1.html">Option3</option> </select></p>

<p dir="ltr"><iframe id="MyFrame" src="MainIntropage2.html" style="width: 
700px; height: 750px;"></iframe><select id="MySelectMenu"><option 
value="Option1page2.html">Option1</option><option 
value="Opion2page2.html">Option2</option><option 
value="Option3page2.html">Option3</option> </select></p>

<p dir="ltr"><iframe id="MyFrame" src="MainIntropage3.html" style="width: 
700px; height: 750px;"></iframe><select id="MySelectMenu"><option 
value="Option1page3.html">Option1</option><option 
value="Opion2page3.html">Option2</option><option 
value="Option3page3.html">Option3</option> </select></p>

<p dir="ltr"><iframe id="MyFrame" src="MainIntropage2.html" style="width: 
700px; height: 750px;"></iframe><select id="MySelectMenu"><option 
value="Option1page4.html">Option1</option><option 
value="Opion2page4.html">Option2</option><option 
value="Option3page4.html">Option3</option> </select></p>

<p dir="ltr"><button onclick="newSrc();">Get Chart</button></p>
```

I’m trying to avoid building individual pages and using a simple drop down to navigate to those pages. It seems I could make it dynamic this way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some sort of code available that you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with?

Comment: @MTSnow It's still unclear what you're asking. We need more code to help you effectively. It's certainly a 'minimal' example, but not complete or verifiable. Give us a way that we can run your example in our browser and tinker with it.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me, new to programming. I Updated the code I have. I'm looking to use one dropdown at the top of the page to control the content of the 4 Iframes which have different sources.

Comment: I think I understand the general idea of what you want, but it's not clear to me how you would control the src of four different iframes with a single dropdown. What would it look like, and how would you want it to work? If you selected option1, would they all change to their option1page?

Comment: I would like the drop down to display options 1-4. If you chose Option 1 then the first iframe would display option 1 page 1, the second iframe would display option 1 page 2, third frame option one page 3 etc. If you chose option 2 the frames would change to option 2 page 1, option 2 page 2 etc.

Comment: use <a> tags in your dropdown and use the `target` attribute to make them navigate the iframe. [a tag target attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)